# Repopulating a Dewalt battery, cell choices

Tags: lithium-ion, 18650

I am replacing the 5 each 18650-13B cells in a Dewalt 20V battery. Is it important the replacement cells are "13B" or can I use other capacity cells or any capacity? thanx, Dacattoo

Comment: If you replace one or a few, the capacities must match the existing. If you replace all, they can have any capacity as long as all have the same.

Answer (score 3):

Winny's comment is absolutely correct.

Replacing a single cell it makes only sense, if the battery pack has only seen a few use cycles and broke early.

Otherwise it is better to replace all cells with new and identical cells.

Let me add the [13B (13L) cells are high drain type](https://www.samsungsdi.com/lithium-ion-battery/power-devices/power-tool.html)  with allowed max. current of 23 A. The new cells, whatever capacity, should also have such specification!

So for a full replacement the cells must not be Samsung and can have another capacity, but the **peak current rating must be the same or higher** as the original cells, else you may create a very bright torch ;-)

When replacing cells in power tool battery packs one should carefully determine the rated peak current capability of the new cells to be at least the same as the old ones. If the new cells are not specified for high discharge current, and/or do not provide a convincing data sheet, it is better to stay away from them for this purpose - for your own safety.